# d3 linear scale doesn't include end values in very basic case

Tags: d3.js

I've come across a strange case in my d3 charts where the scale.ticks(n) call does not return what I would expect.

```js
$("#myResult").append("[0-.15] 4 ticks : ")
$("#myResult").append(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, .15]).ticks(4).toString());
$("#myResult").append("<br/>")

$("#myResult").append("[0-.20] 5 ticks : ")
$("#myResult").append(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, .20]).ticks(5).toString());
$("#myResult").append("<br/>")

$("#myResult").append("[0-.25] 6 ticks : ")
$("#myResult").append(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, .25]).ticks(6).toString());
$("#myResult").append("<br/>")

$("#myResult").append("[0-.3] 7 ticks : ")
$("#myResult").append(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, .3]).ticks(7).toString());
$("#myResult").append("<br/>")

$("#myResult").append("[0-.35] 8 ticks : ")
$("#myResult").append(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, .35]).ticks(8).toString());
$("#myResult").append("<br/>")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="myResult"></div>
```

Sorry for the cludgy example here but I think it shows my point. I would expect each of these to return nice multiples of .05 in the way that [0,.2] and [0,.25] do.   I thought ticks() would aim for multiples of 2 and 5 in the lowest power of 10 it could.

Comment: If you want specific tick values to occur, use `.tickValues()`. D3 scales have some internal logic that may not always do what you want, as you've discovered.

Comment: @Lars Yeah, I was hoping to stay away from specifying values with .tickValues(). I thought the internal logic would cover this particular case.

Comment: You can try running `.nice()` on the scale, but in general using `.tickValues()` is the only sure way.